# rxjs catchError operator not propagating the error after the Angular router navigate method is called

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

I have a decorator which adds a catchError operator to the observable returned by the decorated method. When an error happens Angular router is used to navigate the back to a default route.

```js
export function redirectOnError(route: string) {
  return function (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method= descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function () {
      return method.apply(this, arguments).pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.router.navigate([route]);//this exists on the decorated object
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

This works but the error does not propagate even though `return throwError(error);` is hit (tested). If the navigate method call is commented out the error is correctly propagated.
Any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are losing the context here, can you change it to an arrow function and try again

```
 descriptor.value = () => {
  return method.apply(this, arguments).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.router.navigate([route]);//this exists on the decorated object
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I was actually thinking the same, I tested it but if I do that the method is not invoked at all

Comment: to clarify my previous comment: if I use an arrow function here the decorated method generates error ad it use this internally and the context is changed